# Timing color changing after click

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle, timing

I implemented this but it's not working, i want the text color to change on click and changing it back after a while. It works without the timer, and with it doesn't do anything, no errors on console either.

JS:

```
function toggle_color(ele) {

    $(ele).parent().css({
        "color": "red"
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(ele).parent().css({
            "color": "#000000"
        }, 2000);
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
   <button onclick="toggle_color(this);">
      text inside button
   </button>
   text to toggle color
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the timer code, you're applying the duration to the `.css` call, and not the `timeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(ele).parent().css({
        "color": "#000000"
    }); //duration WAS here, should be below
}, 2000)
  //^^ duration here
```

Comment: Ho my god... Thanks, this completely passed by me.. I thought it was a more complex problem. Thanks